# searching committed Files on comments

Tags: cvs

Is there a way in CVS to search all the files in a cvs repository having a particular keyword in the comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly; you can use `cvs log` to get the list of files, write them into a new file `fileList` and then search this list with `xargs -i grep /dev/null "{}" < fileList`.

The odd "/dev/null" is to force `grep` to print file names.